# Showing $[H(x + t) − H(x − t)]\,\delta'(t) = −2\delta(x)\delta(t)$, for Dirac delta $\delta$ and Heaviside $H$

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

How to show that
$$[H(x + t) − H(x − t)]\,\delta'(t) = −2\delta(x)\delta(t)$$
where $\delta$ represents the Dirac delta function and $H$ represents the Heaviside function?

I have tried testing the convolution on both sides with a test function $\phi(x,t)$ but it doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The objects $H(x-t) \delta^{'} (t)$ and $\delta(x) \delta (t)$ are not well-defined in the standard theory of distribution. Perhaps you want to consider tensor product? For example, it can be shown that: $[H(x+t)-H(x-t)] \otimes \delta^{'} (t) = -2 \delta(x+t) \otimes \delta(t)$ assuming the test function is odd w.r.t. x. But I'm not sure this is what you need. For an example on tensor products of distributions, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3854563/an-integral-involving-two-dirac-deltas-function/3854914#3854914

Comment: You use the term "convolution". Isn't your question $[H(x + t) − H(x − t)] \color{red}{\star} \delta'(t) = −2\delta(x) \color{red}{\star} \delta(t)$ ?

Comment: ... at least for the LHS. The RHS could be as @Saleh said a tensor product...

Answer (score 0):

1. Define the 2D [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))
   $$ u[f]~:=~ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \! \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}t f(x,t) [H(x+t)-H(x-t)],\tag{1}$$
   and
   $$ v[f]~:=~ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \! \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}t f(x,t) \delta(t)~:=~\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \! \mathrm{d}x ~ f(x,0),\tag{2}$$
   for a test function $f$.
2. The product distribution $$w~=~uv~=0\tag{3}$$ is well-defined.
   In fact $w$ is the zero distribution. Proof of eq. (3):
   $$\begin{align} u[f]~:=~&vw[f]\cr
   ~=~& \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \! \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}t f(x,t) [H(x+t)-H(x-t)]\delta(t)\cr
   ~=~&0. \end{align}\tag{4}$$
3. OP's title relation is a consequence of that the derivative
   $$0~=~\partial_tw~=~(\partial_tu) v + u(\partial_tv) \tag{5}$$
   vanish as well, and that
   $$(\partial_tu) v~=~2\delta^2. \tag{6}$$
   Proof of eq. (6):
   $$\begin{align}(\partial_tu) v[f]~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \! \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}t f(x,t) \partial_t[H(x+t)-H(x-t)]\delta(t)\cr
   ~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \! \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}t f(x,t) [\delta(x+t)+\delta(x-t)]\delta(t)\cr
   ~=~&2f(0,0)~=~2\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \! \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}t f(x,t)\delta^2(x,t)\cr
   ~=:~& 2\delta^2[f].\end{align} \tag{7}$$